# Add attribute to admin model Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I'm trying to add an attribute to my user admin model, but it doesn't work,

here is what I succeded to do (I want to add inactivity field):

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import User
    
    
    class usersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'inactivity')


    admin.site.register(User, usersAdmin)
```

Here is my model code:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.TextField(max_length=140, default='uid', primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.TextField(max_length=140, default='cn')
    last_name = models.TextField(max_length=140, default='givenName')
    inactivity = models.IntegerField(default=500)

    def _str_(self):
        return self
```

The error occurs when I'm trying to access to my added field from my views:

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        data['username'] = self.user.username
        data['first_name'] = self.user.first_name
        data['last_name'] = self.user.last_name
        data['inactivity'] = self.user.inactivity
        print(self.user)
        return data
```

the error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oussa\.virtualenvs\SYNEIKA-v3YFud-O\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\oussa\.virtualenvs\SYNEIKA-v3YFud-O\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\oussa\.virtualenvs\SYNEIKA-v3YFud-O\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\oussa\.virtualenvs\SYNEIKA-v3YFud-O\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\oussa\.virtualenvs\SYNEIKA-v3YFud-O\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\oussa\.virtualenvs\SYNEIKA-v3YFud-O\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\oussa\.virtualenvs\SYNEIKA-v3YFud-O\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\oussa\.virtualenvs\SYNEIKA-v3YFud-O\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\oussa\.virtualenvs\SYNEIKA-v3YFud-O\lib\site-packages\rest_framework_simplejwt\views.py", line 27, in post
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  File "C:\Users\oussa\.virtualenvs\SYNEIKA-v3YFud-O\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 220, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "C:\Users\oussa\.virtualenvs\SYNEIKA-v3YFud-O\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 422, in run_validation
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "C:\Users\oussa\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\SYNEIKA\backend\ldapapp\views.py", line 85, in validate
    data['inactivity'] = self.user.inactivity
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'inactivity'
```

PS: I'm using LDAP auth backend in setting.py I have:

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, LDAPGroupQuery,PosixGroupType

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://192.0.0.1'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = 'cn=admin,dc=syneika,dc=com'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = '123'
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch('ou=users,dc=syneika,dc=com',ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(uid=%(user)s)')
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch('ou=groups,dc=syneika,dc=com',ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(objectClass=top)')
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = PosixGroupType(name_attr="cn")
AUTH_LDAP_MIRROR_GROUPS = True

    # Populate the Django user from the LDAP directory.
AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = (
        LDAPGroupQuery("cn=Active,ou=groups,dc=syneika,dc=com")
    )

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
        "first_name": "givenName",
        "last_name": "sn",
        "email": "mail",
        "username": "uid",
        "password": "userPassword"
}
AUTH_LDAP_PROFILE_ATTR_MAP = {
        "home_directory": "homeDirectory"
}
AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
        "is_active": (
        LDAPGroupQuery("cn=Active,ou=groups,dc=syneika,dc=com")
    ),
        "is_staff": (
        LDAPGroupQuery("cn=Staff,ou=groups,dc=syneika,dc=com")
    ),
        "is_superuser": (
        LDAPGroupQuery("cn=Superuser,ou=groups,dc=syneika,dc=com")
    )
}
    
AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600
    
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
    
    # Keep ModelBackend around for per-user permissions and maybe a local
    # superuser.
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Comment: Did you run migrations to sync the model in the database...?

Comment: @AbubakariUmarblacKrussainUma Yes migrate --fake

Comment: I guess that's why is didn't work, i will suggest you go into the root directorymigrations and delete all migrations and then sync it back into the database then everything should be fine from there! --fake migration doesn't actually makes the migration sync in your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that in my view (TokenView) I'm referencing to the Auth user and not the User Model in my models.

So to add another attributes to the Authenticating user (provided by Django by default), I must associate the Auth user to another model and add the attributes I want, I found it here : [Django Profiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity = models.IntegerField(default=500)

    def _str_(self):
        return self
```

Answer (score 1):

Please go into your root directory and delete all migrations from the root directory leaving only **init** file then go back into your command console and apply the migrations before you sync it to your database with migrate. Your from problem seems to come from the --fake migrate as it does not actually sync it to the databased.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did exactly what you told but it didn't work! I'm using PostgreeSQL, I checked the tables and they don't contain the attributes I added

Comment: Well PostgreSQL can be complicated sometimes, if you don't really have any important data in your database i suppose you delete whole database and create a new one before you apply  migration. it should work when you do it that way. please note! Not fake migrate !!

Comment: Thank you, for your help, though it didn't solve my problem I figured out that in my view (TokenView) I'm referencing to the Auth user and not the User Model in my models.